# How much datapoints must be in a subset of a dataset before the subset is representative of that parent dataset?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-structure, sufficient-statistics

It makes sense to me that a randomly sampled subset of a dataset should still be theoretically representative of its parent. When you take data and split into training and test sets, you assume that the training and test sets are representative of the dataset as a whole, at least in terms of its target distribution in the case of ML. But is there some minimum sample size that ceases to be representative?

Say I have a set of data $D$ and take a subset of that dataset $d \subset D$. Suppose the dataset $D$ consists of $(x_i,y_i)$ pairs of input and target. How many points will need to be in $d$ before the target distribution of $d$ mirrors that of $D$?

As per a comment, to clarify what I mean by being representative..

I claim that you can tell if a subset $d$ is representative of $D$ if for each label the ratio of its value counts to the size of the dataset is preserved from $D$ to $d$.

For example, the ratio of label $a$'s frequency in $D$ to the size of $D$, which I'll denote as $\tilde D_a$ is

$$\tilde D_a = \frac{f_a}{len(D)}$$

Where $f_a$ is the frequency of label $a$ in $D$. I argue that $d$ is representative to $D$ if:

$$\tilde d_i = \tilde D_i \ \forall i \in l$$

Where $l$ are the labels for the target variables in $D$.

It theoretically means if I plotted a histogram of the target/class distribution for $d$, it should have the same shape as $D$.

Comment: How do you measure the representatives-ness of $d$ within $D$?

Comment: @Randall Compare histograms of the target  crudely, or to do so thoroughly, keep track of each target label's value count in $D$ proportional to the size of $D$ and compare to each target label's value count in $d$ proportional to the size of $d$.

Comment: For example, if label $A$, $B$, and $C$ made up of 25%, 50% and 25% of the labels respectively in $D$, if label $A$ $B$ and $C$ made up 25%, 50% and 25% of the labels respectively in $d$, then $d$ is representative of $D$.

Comment: I feel for large data sets this will never happen.  I was expecting some sort of "tolerance" measure.

Comment: This is just an attempt for me to try to ask the question of what makes data representative. If there is a more standard way of answering what I'm trying to ask using tolerance, I'd be more than happy to be led in that direction or to hear more about it!

Comment: A small sample of a population may differ from the population in terms of label frequency, but low N should be accounted for with appropriate statistical analysis, resulting in wide confidence intervals around any parameters (like label frequency) you'd want to estimate. Just a handful of samples might show large differences in absolute frequencies from the true values, but the paucity of data will result in wide CIs likely showing the sampled data is *not inconsistent* with the population values.